# Excel formula to copy and paste a cell with the same column letter but increase the row amount by 7 as you paste

Tags: excel, row

Excel formula to copy and paste a cell with the same column letter but increase the row amount by 7 as you paste.

For example, set a cell on a new worksheet to `='INPUT'!H7`

The next cell I want to `='INPUT'!H14`

When I paste this formula again I want it to keep the same worksheet name and column, but keep increasing the row by 7.  `='INPUT'!H21`

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to drag your formulas *down*, use this one, say in `C1`:

```
=INDEX('INPUT'!H:H, 7*ROW(A1))
```

it will give you value from `'INPUT'!H7` in `C1`, value from `'INPUT'!H14` in `C2` and so on.

---

If you're going to drag your formulas *across*, use this one, say in `C1`:

```
=INDEX('INPUT'!$H:$H, 7*COLUMN(A1))
```

it will give you value from `'INPUT'!H7` in `C1`, value from `'INPUT'!H14` in `D1` and so on.